# Spring Integration with JMS configuration

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration

I'm trying to get a basic Spring Integration configuration running with JMS.

The problem is that I seem to be making the connection (as per the log), but I'm not recieving any messages on my topic.

This is my configuration:

```
<!-- Channels -->
<jms:channel id="inputChannel" queue-name="test.queue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<!-- Consumers -->    
<jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" destination="requestQueue" channel="inputChannel" extract-payload="true" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <integration:poller time-unit="SECONDS" fixed-rate="5"/>
</jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

<integration:service-activator id="testActivator" input-channel="inputChannel" ref="testServiceActivator" auto-startup="true" method="handle">
</integration:service-activator>

<!-- Bean definitions -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/>             
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="test.topic"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testServiceActivator" class="com.paddypower.financials.integration.PriceDistributionServiceActivator"/>
```

I've enabled DEBUG level on the root logger and it says that `jmsIn` is successfully started and that it's connected to the ActiveMQ server, but I'm not receiving any messages, either with the `service-activator` or the `inbound-channel-adapter`.

I can also see that the producer is sending messages through the ActiveMQ web interface.

So can anyone see anything wrong with the configuration or know of a way I can debug it further ?

Thanks,

Comment: Question @Simeon : You mentioned that "test.topic" is a topic, requestQueue is being defined as a queue though - any reason why it is not ActiveMQTopic?

Comment: Try using a message-driven-channel-adapter instead (generally more efficient anyway) and set TRACE level logging.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen I just found it and you were right this is the problem I changed the implementation to topic and everything works now. Add an answer so I can accept it please :)

Comment: @GaryRussell How to define a listener or a service for message-driven-channel-adapter that should be invoked upon received messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the bean definition of requestQueue from `ActiveMQQueue` to `ActiveMQTopic` should fix it.

```
<bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="test.topic"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: to avoid further confusion, I would also recommend renaming the bean to "requestTopic" ;)